# How to replace all string that match with regular expression in JavaScript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose I have a string. Imagine, the string is

> "*Bangladesh is a **{{beautiful}}** country. I **{{love}}** you Bangladesh.*"

Here **love** word is wrapped up **{{}}** which indicates that I need a dash field/input field so that the student/user can fill it up. How can I display it with a dash/input field as a replacement for beautiful and love words? such as:

> ***Bangladesh is a ____ country. I ____ you Bangladesh***

```js
const searchRegExp = /{{.*.*}}.*/g;
var quiz_gap_question = 'Bangladesh is a {{beautiful}} country. I {{love}} you Bangladesh.'

console.log(quiz_gap_question.replace(searchRegExp, '___'));
```

But this regular expression is not working. How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const searchRegExp = /\{\{.+?\}\}/g;
var quiz_gap_question = 'Bangladesh is a {{beautiful}} country. I {{love}} you Bangladesh.'

console.log(quiz_gap_question.replace(searchRegExp, '___'));
```

see [here](https://regexr.com/7016d) for explanation of the regex pattern